# DeleteObject method is missing in Entity Framework 4.1

Tags: entity-framework, c#-4.0, entity-framework-4.1, edmx

This is driving me crazy. I am getting error that

> object doesn't contain definition for DeleteObject.

Here is my line of code that produces an error:

```
ctx.Tanks.DeleteObject(Tank);
```

I tried to reference another object from another `edmx` file that my friend has created and then everything is fine, `DeleteObject` exists. I don't think I miss any references in my project.

And project itself contains edmx file and I used `DBContext` to create POCOs.

Any ideas?

Comment: Are you both using the same version of entity framework with the same templates?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The `DbContext` API defines `DbSet`s not `ObjectSet`s. [DbSet](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg696460%28v=vs.103%29.aspx) has a `Remove` method not `DeleteObject` method. You need to first decide which API you are going to use. If it the `ObjectContext` or `DbContext`.

Comment: Thanks. I realized that yesterday.

Comment: So with DBContext there is no way to remove parent and all children related like the DeleteObject does in Objectcontext?

Comment: @DavieDave You can with `DbSet`. If you have configured cascade delete for the child table, then it will automatically get deleted.

Answer (score 1):

```
  [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Delete(IEnumerable<int> employeeIdsToDelete)
        {
            var lstemployee = _db.StudentEmployees.Where(x => employeeIdsToDelete.Contains(x.Id));
            foreach (var item in lstemployee)
            {
                _db.StudentEmployees.Remove(item);
            }
            _db.SaveChanges();

            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
```

Comment: There was already an accepted answer to this post. If you'd like to contribute, please expand upon your answer with additional detail and context.